# pybind11: how to wrap c++ function that takes std::vector<double> as argument to avoid data copy

Tags: c++, numpy, pybind11

c++ function:

```cpp
    double cpp_func(const std::vector<double>& x) {
        return ...;
    }
```

I want to use `pybind11` to wrap this function to python which accept numpy array as argument and `x` may be very large so I want to pass the numpy array by reference or pointer.

Comment: A numpy array is not an std::vector, so there is no way to wrap *this* function to avoid copying. You need a function that accepts a numpy array argument instead.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the array you want to pass in start its life? If you have control over its creation, then you can make it an std::vector and take a numpy view on that vector's data(). That way, you can use both at the same time: the vector when in C++-land, the numpy array when on the Python side.

Only caveat is that the vector should not resize during the lifetime of the numpy view (or you know its maximum size ever, and reserve() that memory just after creation).

If the vector never resizes, then you can make the vector a data member of the view to sync the life times.